# How to get a json format like this?

Tags: php, json

I want to create a json response like this, shown below. How can it be done by modifying below php code. I tried many ways but result was not there.

Please find the link to the editor

https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/concepts/image/manager
Current response which i get from the code is below

```
[  
   "http://cloudpanda.org//images/media/01fe5273acbd47e413b02bbcfae5a20ac868d037.jpg",
   "http://cloudpanda.org//images/media/022fa4051066da105688a8ca0f83d222cef3739d.jpg",
]
```

Expected response which I need from the code is below:

```
[  
       {  
          "url":"http://cloudpanda.org//images/media/01fe5273acbd47e413b02bbcfae5a20ac868d037.jpg",
       },
       {  
          "url":"http://cloudpanda.org//images/media/022fa4051066da105688a8ca0f83d222cef3739d.jpg",
       },

    ]
```

Current php code looks like this:

```
<?php
// Array of image links to return.
$response = array();

// Image types.
$image_types = array(
    "image/gif",
    "image/jpg",
    "image/pjpeg",
    "image/jpeg",
    "image/pjpeg",
    "image/png",
    "image/x-png"
);

// Filenames in the uploads folder.
$fnames = scandir("images/media/");

// Check if folder exists.
if ($fnames) {
    // Go through all the filenames in the folder.
    foreach ($fnames as $name) {
        // Filename must not be a folder.
        if (!is_dir($name)) {
            // Check if file is an image.
            if (in_array(mime_content_type(getcwd() . "/images/media/" . $name), $image_types)) {
                // Add to the array of links.
                array_push($response, "http://cloudpanda.org/images/media/" . $name);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Folder does not exist, respond with a JSON to throw error.
else {
    $response        = new StdClass;
    $response->error = "Images folder does not exist!";
}

$response = json_encode($response);

// Send response.
echo stripslashes($response);
?>
```

Comment: what's your issue here?

Comment: I need to get the response variable as the json code above. Currenly i am only getting a list of urls only i need to get it like this "url":"https://i.froala.com/assets/photo1.jpg",

Comment: your link is bland

Comment: I updated my question please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your code like this, change

```
array_push($response, "http://cloudpanda.org/images/media/" . $name);
```

to

```
$response[]['url'] = "http://cloudpanda.org/images/media/" . $name;
```